# Read a title of OneSignal Notification in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, onesignal

I use PhoneGap Build and OneSignal.
How can I read a title of notification in PhoneGap Project.
There is my code

```
......
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var iosSettings = {};
    iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt"] = true;
    iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL"] = false;

    window.plugins.OneSignal.startInit( "*************************", "************")
                            .handleNotificationReceived(didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack)
                            .handleNotificationOpened(didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack)
                            .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
                            .iOSSettings(iosSettings)
                            .endInit();
}
};

function didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack(jsonData) {
alert('RECEIVE: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}
function didOpenRemoteNotificationCallBack (jsonData) {
alert('OPEN: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
}

app.initialize();
```

How to get a TITLE when Notification receive?
I found a Documentations but I don't understand
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap-sdk#section-receiving-notifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by calling `jsonData.payload.title` in your `didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack` function. See Onesignal's [NotificationReceivedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/cordova-sdk#section--notificationreceivedhandler-) documentation for a full list of properties.

Comment: Thanks! How I can get an additionalData like 'URL'??

Comment: ’jsonData.payload.additionalData’